# how to get application item value in multiple application in a same work-space in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to access application item values in multiple application in the same workspace and the applications are authenticated by clone the session. I am able to access application item value in the same application using this(i.e &G_application_item_name. ). But In the same way, I tried to access it in another application. But I couldn't get a value of application item. Any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the Application Item don't forget to put the scope on 'Global'. This will allow you to use this AI between Applications.

Answer (score 0):

The &P1_ITEM. syntax is case sensitive. I think one of few within Oracle that is.

And as Olivier points out, Global scope required for the application items.

I tend to 'join' application security with the authentication scheme cookie name.